# Making a highscore table in python?

Tags: python, file, pygame, external

I'm making the game snake for a project for school in python. I am using the pygame module and have coded the whole game apart from the highscores table! The deadline is for tomorrow and i'm beginning to loose hope!

Basically I have got all the user input which ones enter is pressed the user's name and score is put into an external file called highscores.txt. I then have to read this file when the highscore section is opened and sort out the data from top 1 - 10! I just do not understand the concept though.

any help is appreciated!

Comment: paste your code here. In my experience, if you can get to programming with pygame, writing to a file and sorting scores(`ints`) is 'childs play`

Comment: Don't paste the code if it's too long. What is it that you don't understand? How to read the file and sort it? Or is it how to display it?

Comment: Okay the code is way to long! I can easily read the file, I think its more sorting and then displaying that I can't understand!

Comment: I have this to add the data to the list but how do Iread +sort?                                                                                                                  adding_highscore =  open("highscore.txt","a")
                adding_highscore.writelines(list)
                adding_highscore.writelines(',')
                adding_highscore.writelines(counter)
                adding_highscore.writelines("\n")
                adding_highscore.close()
                gameDisplay.fill(black)
                title('Your Highscore Is Saved!', green, 100,400)
                highscore()

Comment: I think as well a friend of mine said something about adding a linear search to find the ',' on each line and then any information before that gets displayed under the names and anything after that get's displayed under the score section. But it's more how to sort this information!

Answer (score 1):

This will help you read the file

```
with open('highscore.txt') as f:
lines = f.readlines()
```

Lines is an array where each element is a line in your text file.
I'm not sure what kind of format your file is in but this might help you: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm